# QiDi i-Fast print in parallel

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, dual-nozzle

I'm playing with the QiDi Print software to compare the slicing results with mine (Dremel 3D45). One of the reasons I'm going to buy it is the printing in parallel using the two nozzles:

[image]

But I'm not able to set up the slicer correctly. As an example I set both extruders with the same PLA. I did the following steps:

1. load the objects (two instances of the same or even two different objects)
2. select the left one and press "print with extruder 2"
3. select the right one and press "print with extruder 1"
4. in the slicer parameters window, if I try to set the extruder for build plate adhesion it is set for *both* extruders:

[image]

[image]

So I cannot set Extruder 1 for object printed with extruder 1 and the same for the other.
Hence I tried to select one object to enable the "per model settings". But, looking at the settings to customize, the Dual extrusion panel shows nothing:

[image]

I enabled the visibility of *all* settings.
In any case, trying to slice with these settings, it add a weird wall around all the objects:

[image]

I never seen such a wall and I don't understand why is there and how to avoid it.

Finally, how to set up the slicer in order to print two objects in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ooze shield setting]

The question regarding the wall is covered in the advanced settings for Additions. In the screen capture above, you can see that it is turned on. Ostensibly, it's used to scrub off the previous filament oozing as it sits idle.

I don't have an i-fast and cannot identify the setting you require for duplication printing. Terminology is tricky; my IDEX printer slicer calls it duplication printing and mirror printing.

As an aside, you should have a contact email for QIDI tech support. My experience with the email system is next-day response.